# doInbackground method not running after application on resume

Tags: android, android-asynctask

im fetching image data via HttpURLConnection , now after 1st time fetchinng the image data onPostexcute that image is showing in the imageview (onresume) but at that time server update the image data(image is changed) and now doinbackground not working .i want instantly change the image view image as soon as server change the image .but its not working instantly . I need to restart the app and then its going to change .i want to change the image instantly help me

Comment: How will your App know that the Image from the server has changed? Try Firebase Cloud Messaging or doing periodic requests.

Comment: You will need to have a `timer` or a `service` that check for new image on interval to enable the app to fetch new image from server. Try @Xenolion options above

Comment: Server send me a update info with that image . If update info is true thats mean server changed that image . But problem i cant get the update infor working on the run time .mean when my app is on resume position with the updated info the app is not changing the image

Comment: how did the server send the update. Is it in a listener or what, you can immediately load into image at the position where server send the updated image. Adding the code where the server send update in your question will be useful

Comment: When i post request to the http , it send me the data(image data) and at the same time i need post another http call to get some update info .but the problem is after 1st time image download and showing into imageview ,the update api not working in the background

Answer (score 0):

You should use a timer to check for new image at interval, but the downside is that it will contribute greatly to the app memory usage and if it doing too much work can freeze the app but that is unlikely to happen on android device from **LOLLIPOP** and above

```
...
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

   ...
   Timer timer = new Timer();

   ...
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       //load you image from url to image view

   }, 1000, 2000);
   ...
```

Dont forget to cancel you timer when you exit the program

Or you could use Service alternatively but it probably too much for the job else you can use the service for more function in your app

```
...
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        //load you image from url to image view

    }
}
```

Note: don't forget to de-register the service in your activity.
You can alternatively look into [**Firebase Cloud Messaging**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) as suggested by @xenolion

Comment: The problem is - there is 2 asynctask in the activity one for fetching the data (which is now avaible in the server ) another is for to know the update info . But the main problem is when 1st asynctask execute it load the image but in the background update asynctask is not working (i want it work and change the image as par update info )

Comment: can you post your async task code that if fetching data on the server and the background update asyn task code. You can format it to just basic info if you don't want to compromise some information